# How can I replace last part in structure this.props.{myName}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jsx

I have name that I get from component(for example "popular" and I get it by "this.props.name") and I need to push that name in this structure: "this.props.{name which I get} => this.props.popular", but I don't know how I can do this.
I tried do this:

```
let needName = this.props.`${this.props.name}`;
```

But it didn't work. I know that it's strange question but I need to solve it by this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to use a variable to dynamically create the reference to a property in an object, you can use bracket notation:

```
let needName = this.props[this.props.name];
```

For more information, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties